# Window winterize Exterior on vinyl siding house

Tags: windows

I am trying to make a plastic window frame to put on my exterior windows on my house that has vinyl siding,  but not sure how to hang them up??

Comment: Does the house have the vinyl siding, or the windows are made of vinyl.  Screws will work, if not wanting screw holes, something like silicon caulk might hold enough, but needs to be held together till it sets.  There are some temporary adhesives also.

Comment: It's a very old house, and vinyl siding on the outside of house. Some windows have been broken so are replaced with a thick plastic,  so my windows are not winterize.  I am making a framed plastic covering,  but not sure how to hang it up on the siding.

Comment: The cover with the frame should be attached to the window frames not the siding. If there is a reason attachment cannot be to the window frame, please explain in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you want is what used to be called storm windows.  They screw/nail onto the window frames, not the siding.  Make/cut them to fit inside where the siding stops at the windows.  Might also want to look at inside window insulation kits to reduce drafts.

Comment: Care to [edit] to share a picture of the frames you've made and the window frames you're attaching them to? That would probably help us help you.